# FTP server | Filezilla | issues connecting

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, ftp

so I am trying to setup an FTP server (Filezilla) on my windows 2012 server.
I have installed filzilla server and set the port to 14144 (not the default 14147) I have also ensured the the service is running.

Next I created a user in the filezilla interface, like so:

[image]

[image]

However, when I try to connect via the FTP using my home computer (not on the server) it does not let me connect. Error message:

```
Status: Connecting to [ip address]...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I have even tried adding port 14144 to my inbound rules on the firewall... still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the port when connecting from your home computer. Most FTP clients including Filezilla will attempt to connect on the default port 21 (FTP) and 22 (SFTP).

Comment: I have added port 21 to firewall and it seems to be working.